# What API (or lib) do I should use to sniff local network ports on Mac OS X (Cocoa)?

Tags: cocoa, http, macos, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to make a simple HTTP sniffer (like [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/6647)) development testing purpose.
HTTPFox is good enough, but I should automate some kind of test. (No detail yet)
But I have no idea how to do this.

What kind of API or libs do I should use to do this on Mac?

Cocoa will be great but any lower level ways are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use libpcap/tcpdump. http://www.tcpdump.org/

Comment: ...and `man pcap`.  There's no Cocoa wrapper for libpcap supplied by Apple.  A Google search found [packetsniffer](https://github.com/nark/packetsniffer) and [CapKit](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/CapKit.shtml); I have no experience with them myself.